# DLL/exe Injection into running process

Tags: memory, exe, reverse-engineering, dll-injection, malware-detection

Is it normal to inject DLL or exe program into running process? After injection, I'm able to read process memory showing injected DLL/exe contents.

Comment: Yes, you can change the value inside the memory like using `Cheat Engine`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is "normal" to inject a DLL or exe into a running process.  If your application has no other efficient way of doing it's job, and you must inject a DLL into other processes, by all means do it.

[CreateRemoteThreadEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405484(v=vs.85).aspx) is a Windows API Function, once your thread is running in the remote process you just call [LoadLibrary()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) to load your DLL into into the process.

These are Windows API functions, as long as your account is an admin account there is nothing stopping you from injecting a DLL, these are well documents functions from Microsoft and plenty of legitimate software use DLL injection.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: Did it answer your question?  If so, please upvote or mark as solution if you haven't already :)

Comment: @GuidedHacking is it possible to inject a DLL into an application such as a compiler and so without admin permissions?